# Suddenly not working on Ubuntu Digital Ocean: requests error for only Google

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu, digital-ocean, urllib3

It was working fine a week ago, but all of a sudden it stopped working.

Steps to reproduce:

```
Python 2.7.12 (default, Nov 12 2018, 14:36:49)
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import requests
>>> requests.get('http://yahoo.com')
<Response [200]>
>>> requests.get('http://google.com')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 67, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 53, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 480, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 609, in send
    history = [resp for resp in gen] if allow_redirects else []
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 211, in resolve_redirects
    **adapter_kwargs
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 588, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 437, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='www.google.com', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fc5076e7950>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -5] No address associated with hostname',))
```

Expected output:

```
<Response [200]>
```

What is weird is that it works for other websites, but not Google

Comment: Perhaps your DNS is having issues?

Comment: @JohnGordon `nslookup google.com` and `ping google.com` works

Comment: Have you managed to resolve this issue? I'm experiencing the same thing now. `nslookup` and `ping` works, and requests even sometimes connects to the endpoint, but often fails for no apparent reason. It started out all by itself with no changes.